# guess-TeX-master bug?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm trying to use the guess-TeX-master function (from [emacswiki auctex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX)) but I get this error:

Wrong type argument: stringp, nil

My elisp knowledge is quite poor. Does somebody know the problem?

**[EDIT]**

This error was because I forgot do it the latex hook.

Anyway I trying to do something different. I want to find the file (in the same directory) that has the "begin{document}". Because my elisp skills are poor, I do it in a script:

In my .emacs:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook  
  (lambda ()  
    (setq TeX-master (execvp "guess-TeX-master"  
      (file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))))))
```

execvp defun is here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand

The guess-TeX-master script is:

```
grep "begin{document}" $1/*.tex | cut -d ':' -f 1 | tr -d '\n'
```

How to do the same using elisp only?

Comment: Use `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET`, and then trigger the error again. That will provide you with a stack trace. If you post the contents of the stack trace, that would help to debug the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste your code(at paste.lisp.org and share the link here) so we can find out if it really has syntactic issue.. Basically from what I understand you are trying to use a wrong argument for the operator...